# Get uniqe ID from teamspeak link (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to scrape a team speak Uniqe ID off of a team speak user link. I have tried multiple regex's to get data in between variables but I'm not sure how to get data after the 3rd / and stop at the =

Here is an example of a UID Link:

```
[URL=client://958/noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=~Username]Username[/URL]
```

The data I need to grab is:

```
noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=
```

The 958 is random so I can't use that to grab data.

Comment: Could be simpler to explode on '/' and get the nth element

Comment: I will go ahead and see what I can do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to grab data from url

```
 $re = "/(?:\\d+\\/)([^~]+)/";
 $str = "[URL=client://958/noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=~Username]Username[/URL]";
 preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches[1]);
```

[image]
[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/mA2yL0/1)

**EDIT** There is slight change in regex see here https://www.regex101.com/r/mA2yL0/2

Comment: glad it works for you, you can accept the answer also, best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you give,

```
<?php
    $reg = '/client:\/\/[0-9]+\/(.+?)~/';
    $x = "[URL=client://958/noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=~Username]Username[/URL]";
    $m = preg_match($reg, $x, $matches);

    print_r ($matches[0]);
?>
```

Produces:

```
noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=
```